# BeautifulSoup: extracting HTML tag attributes

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup

Is there a way to get HTML tag attributes only when `text=True` without specifying the tags.

Example:

```
html=<p class="c4">SOMETEXT</p>
```

I could do:

```
[tag.attrs for tag in soup.findAll('p')]
>>> [[(u'class', u'c1')]]
```

Is there a way to do:

```
[text.attrs for text in soup.findAll(text=True)]
```

Help much appriciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Think you want this as the question has been clarified:

```
[tag.attrs for tag in soup.findAll(True) if tag.string]
```

`.findAll(True)` returns **all** tags in the document, so they'll have an `.attr` even if it's empty, and filter if the tag has `.string` content.

Comment: Thanks, maybe the question was badly phrased, but i meant getting the attrs when text=True while not specifying the tag name.

Comment: @root okay, well in that case have you actually tried running the code you mention in "is there a way to do:"? As I believe that'll actually work... (I wouldn't call it `text` though, `tag` would probably be a better name)

Comment: I tryied but got and error: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<interactive input>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Python26\lib\site-packages\BeautifulSoup.py", line 473, in __getattr__
    raise AttributeError, "'%s' object has no attribute '%s'" % (self.__class__.__name__, attr)
AttributeError: 'Declaration' object has no attribute 'attrs'

Answer (score 1):

```
>>> from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
>>> html = '<p class="c4">SOMETEXT</p><p class="c5"></p>'
>>> soup = bs(html)
>>> [tag.attrs for tag in soup.findAll('p') if tag.string]
[{'class': ['c4']}]
```